# How to set Firebase Analytics custom events in Flutter without passing 'analytics/observer' object in each screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, bloc

I'm setting up [Firebase Analytics Package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics) for my Flutter project. The [sample](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/0b8b6f4df57d56d8b86e3c5adcc5a7606d87f06e/packages/firebase_analytics/example/lib/main.dart#L30) provided in the library passes the `analytics` object for tracking events and `observer` for tracking the tab changes.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 ...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo',
        analytics: analytics,
        observer: observer,
      ),
    );
  }
}

...

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
...
Future<void> _sendAnalyticsEvent() async {
    await analytics.logEvent(
      name: 'test_event',
      parameters: <String, dynamic>{
        'string': 'string',
        'int': 42,
        'long': 12345678910,
        'double': 42.0,
        'bool': true,
      },
    );
    setMessage('logEvent succeeded');
  }
...
}
```

My app consists of a lot of screens where the state is managed via a [Bloc](https://felangel.github.io/bloc/) package. Passing these objects from `mainScreen` all the way down the tree where the events are happening would not be good.

Is there a way to access them without passing them around the widget tree. Or would it work if I create a new object of the class `FirebaseAnalytics` and use the generated object to set an event?

`static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();`

Or should I use Flutter_Bloc as a central place to log and set my Flutter Events?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `provider` package to 'provide' both your analytics and observer down your widget tree.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
      FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
            Provider<FirebaseAnalytics>.value(value: analytics),
            Provider<FirebaseAnalyticsObserver>.value(value: observer),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
            home: MyHomePage(
                title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo',
            ),
        ),
    ); 
  }
}
```

Then in any of your child widgets...

```
Future<void> _sendAnalyticsEvent() async {
    FirebaseAnalytics analytics = Provider.of<FirebaseAnalytics>(context);
    await analytics.logEvent(
      name: 'test_event',
      parameters: <String, dynamic>{
        'string': 'string',
        'int': 42,
        'long': 12345678910,
        'double': 42.0,
        'bool': true,
      },
    );
    setMessage('logEvent succeeded');
  }
```

Now you don't need to pass your Firebase instances to the widget constructors.

Comment: Using `flutter_bloc` would it matter if the `MultiProvider()` is **parent** or **child** of `MultiBlocProvider()` ?

Answer (score 8):

Besides using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or a global class with static parameters, another option is to use `services` with the [GetIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) package.

Just create a class that hold's the `analytics` and `observer`. E.g. like this:

```
class AnalyticsService {
  final FirebaseAnalytics _analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();

  FirebaseAnalyticsObserver getAnalyticsObserver() => FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: _analytics);

  Future logScreens({@required String name}) async {
    await _analytics.setCurrentScreen(screenName: name);
  }

  ... // implement the events you want to track
}
```

Now create a `locator` and register the class as a lazy `singleton`:

```
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

setupServiceLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton<AnalyticsService>(() => AnalyticsService());
}
```

Make the `locator` accessable:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setupServiceLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Now you can access the `service` from everywhere in your app by calling the `locator`.
For example:

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Demo',
  theme: themeData,
  initialRoute: SplashScreen.id,
  routes: routes,
  navigatorObservers: [
    // Access the observer
    locator<AnalyticsService>().getAnalyticsObserver(),
  ],
);
```

}

or

```
 onTap: () {
   locator<AnalyticsService>().logScreens(name: DetailsScreen.id);
 }
```

Comment: hey, can you give me a demo project as you showed us, coz I don't know I want to trying to do that, but can't figure it out, it will be very helpful if you give us an example, Thank you

Comment: Hey @AlwayssBijoy, here is a good explanation and the source of the above code: https://www.filledstacks.com/post/firebase-analytics-and-metrics-in-flutter/

Comment: Thanks! Since I already have GetIt, this is exactly what I ended up doing.

Comment: I like getIt because I am using MultiBlocProvidor. And I am also using audio_service with getIt

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to create a file with all of your global instances. e.g: 
file: **globals.dart** in your *lib* directory.

Content of the  file:

```
class Global {
    static final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
}
```

Then to use it:

```
Global.analytics.logEvent(...)
```

Comment: simplest and easiest. provider, getit, block all the rest are too much hocus pocus

Comment: I am currently doing it exactly like this but the problem is that the screen/ event name is not defined. I'm getting the ones described by flutter like screen_view, session_start, first_open, etc.